# blueimp jQuery File Upload send parameter ASP.Net

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, file-upload, blueimp

I am using 
"https://github.com/i-e-b/jQueryFileUpload.Net" .Net .ashx version of handler of jQuery File Uploader for my .Net project. It is comes in iframe.

I want to send two parameter: "recordId" and "FieldName" for each file upload event. 
is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution;

first when iframe open it searches to list existing files.

```
loadFiles = function (id, field) {
            // Show uploaded files
            $.getJSON($('#fileupload form').prop('action'), { Id: id, Field: field }, function (files) {
                var fu = $('#fileupload').data('fileupload');
                fu._adjustMaxNumberOfFiles(-files.length);

                fu._renderDownload(files)
                .appendTo($('#fileupload .files'))
                .fadeIn(function () {
                    // Fix for IE7 and lower:
                    $(this).show();
                });
            });
        }
```

As you can see above, I add Id and Field name for each record in my solution, so it will check records own folder.
In the codebehind I add this to create session parameter:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session.Add("fuFilePath", "\\");
    }
```

And finally, in the handler there is a control mechanism that gets the path information for all other calls for the field of the record.

```
    public string FILEPATH = "";

    public string StorageRoot(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (context.Session["fuFilePath"] != null)
            FILEPATH = context.Session["fuFilePath"].ToString();
        else
            FILEPATH = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StorageRoot"];

        Directory.CreateDirectory(FILEPATH);
        return FILEPATH; 
    }

    public bool IsReusable { get { return false; } }

    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
        context.Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
        context.Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "private, no-cache");

        if (context.Request.Params["Id"] != null && context.Request.Params["Field"] != null) {
            context.Session["fuFilePath"] = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StorageRoot"] + context.Request.Params["Id"] + "\\" + context.Request.Params["Field"] + "\\"; ;
        }

        HandleMethod(context);
    }
```

For all other calls, it first look at session parameter and get the file path of the record. 
If user open the iframe of fileupload for another field or another record, first, it will list the existing files, so session parameters will be replaced by right ones till new listing activity happens.

It was the easiest way for me.